# How do I reverse each value in a column bit wise for a hex number?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, int, hex, reverse

I have a dataframe which has a column called hexa which has hex values like this. They are of dtype object.

```
               hexa
0  00802259AA8D6204
1  00802259AA7F4504
2  00802259AA8D5A04
```

I would like to remove the first and last bits and reverse the values bitwise as follows:

```
         hexa-rev
0  628DAA592280
1  457FAA592280
2  5A8DAA592280
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll show you the complete solution up here and then explain its parts below:

```
def reverse_bits(bits):
    trimmed_bits = bits[2:-2]
    list_of_bits = [i+j for i, j in zip(trimmed_bits[::2], trimmed_bits[1::2])]
    reversed_bits = [list_of_bits[-i] for i in range(1,len(list_of_bits)+1)]
    return ''.join(reversed_bits)

df['hexa-rev'] = df['hexa'].apply(lambda x: reverse_bits(x))
```

There are possibly a couple ways of doing it, but this way should solve your problem. The general strategy will be defining a function and then using the apply() method to apply it to all values in the column. It should look something like this:

```
df['hexa-rev'] = df['hexa'].apply(lambda x: reverse_bits(x))
```

Now we need to define the function we're going to apply to it. Breaking it down into its parts, we strip the first and last bit by indexing. Because of how negative indexes work, this will eliminate the first and last bit, regardless of the size. Your result is a list of characters that we will join together after processing.

```
def reverse_bits(bits):
    trimmed_bits = bits[2:-2]
```

The second line iterates through the list of characters, matches the first and second character of each bit together, and then concatenates them into a single string representing the bit.

```
def reverse_bits(bits):
    trimmed_bits = bits[2:-2]
    list_of_bits = [i+j for i, j in zip(trimmed_bits[::2], trimmed_bits[1::2])]
```

The second to last line returns the list you just made in reverse order. Lastly, the function returns a single string of bits.

```
def reverse_bits(bits):
    trimmed_bits = bits[2:-2]
    list_of_bits = [i+j for i, j in zip(trimmed_bits[::2], trimmed_bits[1::2])]
    reversed_bits = [list_of_bits[-i] for i in range(1,len(list_of_bits)+1)]
    return ''.join(reversed_bits)
```

I explained it in reverse order, but you want to define this function that you want applied to your column, and then use the apply() function to make it happen.

Comment: Thank you. I now converted this reversed column into a decimal and I am trying to perform a checksum calculation on each digit in the integer and generating a checksum. Do you know how I can start with it?

Comment: Can you describe the calculation you're trying to do and where you're getting stuck? If you're just trying to handle each digit of a decimal number separate, you could convert it to a string, then alist of characters, and then back into integers. You should be able to tackle all of that in one line with a list comprehension.

Then you have an ordered list of each digit in the number to use for your calculations. E.g.

decimal_digits = [int(i) for i in string(decimal)]

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you so much.